# Saving Code to database with laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I need to save code snips and text to a database(like a question on stackoverflow where text and code in a question is saved), what would be the best way to save text and code to database. At the moment i'm only saving it normally or is there a save way to display it back safely.

```
$add = new Question;
$add->description = $request->desc;
$add->save();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking what the 'best' way to save text and code to a database is a bit ambiguous. You might want to be more specific -  how can I save the text and code to the database in a more secure way?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to save to database in Laravel. One of them is Mass Assignment. You need to declare the columns of Database which you want to use. Ex:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['description'];
}
```

Then you can create a Question with an array:

```
$question = App\Question::create(['description' => $request->desc]);
```

And if you set the input name in HTML as the same name as the DB column, you can also save with the request array itself as the input. Ex:

```
$question = App\Question::create($request->all());
```

Check Mass Assignment section of Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment